# overloading the extraction operator >> in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I have to code a clock program in which I could enter the hours, minutes and seconds while overloading the extraction operator. These are my codes:

clockType.h

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class clockType
{
public:
   clockType();
   void getTime();
   friend istream& operator>>(istream&, const clockType);
private:
   int hr, min, sec;
}
```

clockType.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include'clockType.h"
using namespace std;

clockType::clockType()
{
    hr = 0;
    min = 0;
    sec = 0;
}

void clockType::getTime()
{
    while(hr>=24)
        hr = hr - 24;
    while(min>=60)
        min = min - 60;
    while(sec>=60)
        sec = sec - 60;
    cout<<setfill('0')
        <<setw(2)<<hr<<":"
        <<setw(2)<<min<<":"
        <<setw(2)<<sec<<endl;
 }

 istream& operator>>(istream& in, clockType cl)
 {
    in>>cl.hr>>cl.min>>cl.sec;
    return in;
 }
```

entryPoint.cpp

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include'clockType.h'

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   clockType clock;
   cout<<"Enter hr, min, sec";
   cin>>clock;
   clock.getTime();
   return 0;
 }
```

There is no error. My question is, as I enter the hr, min and sec, why does it output 00:00:00? Why doesn't the >> pass its values to the object clock?

Comment: You must **never** use I/O operations without error checking. Any of your operations could fail at any stage, and you must never assume that your variables have meaningful values unless all operations succeed. In particular, you mustn't overwrite your live variables until you are sure that you read valid input.

Comment: I did a C++ course recently which contained this exact problem. If it's homework, don't forget to label it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature of the `operator>>` needs to be

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, clockType& cl)
```

That is, it should accept a *reference* to a `clockType` instance.

Your current code accepts a `clockType` instance so when the operator is invoked a temporary copy of your `clock` is made and the operator works on that. The copy is then discarded, and your original `clock` remains unmodified.

Another issue here is that you are not checking if you successfully read anything from your input stream. Any and all of the `>>` operations on `in` could fail, which could leave `cl` in an unknown state. So first of all you should test for success with something like `if(in >> cl.hr)`.

That's still not enough because the first read operation (into `hr`) could succeed, but the next one could fail; that will leave your `cl` in an unknown state. It would be good if the extraction operator had transaction semantics, i.e. either it updates *all three* members or otherwise it leaves the object in its previous state. One way to do that would be to read into local variables first, and only if all three reads succeed copy the values into `cl`.

Comment: Well, I did that but this error appears: error C2248: 'clockType::hr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'clockType'

Same goes for the min and sec..

Comment: @JulienNicolas: You also need to update the `friend` declaration inside `class clockType` to match the signature of the operator -- that goes without saying.

Answer (score 3):

Your extraction operator should probably change the object you passed to it rather than just the copy of it. That is, you want to make the second argument of your extraction operator a non-const reference, too:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, clockType& cl) { ... }
```

BTW, **always** check that the extraction worked before using the results:

```
if (std::cin >> clock) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, clockType cl)
```

should be:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, clockType &cl)   // (note the &)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the clockType object in your `operator>>` by reference, otherwise it will only read into the function local object.